# Java streams to filter out objects falling in a particular period

Tags: java-8

I need some help writing a code to filter out interest rates for particular period
How do I write a code to filter out for instance all the intersetRate Objects between 2018-08-15 and 2019-11-25

```
PeriodFrom   PeriodEnd     InterestRate
2018-01-01 2018-06-30 8.5
2018-07-01 2018-12-31 7.5
2019-01-01 2019-06-30 9.01
2019-07-01 2019-12-31 8.75
2020-01-06 2020-06-30 9.25
2020-07-01 2020-08-31 9.45
2020-09-01 2020-12-31 9.90
```

For this period , it should return 3 objects

```
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    
    public class InterestRate {
        private final LocalDate periodFrom;
        private final LocalDate periodEnd;
        private final BigDecimal intersetRate;
    
        public InterestRate(LocalDate periodFrom, LocalDate periodEnd,
                            BigDecimal intersetRate) {
            this.periodFrom = periodFrom;
            this.periodEnd = periodEnd;
            this.intersetRate = intersetRate;
        }
    
        public LocalDate getPeriodFrom() {
            return periodFrom;
        }

    public LocalDate getPeriodEnd() {
        return periodEnd;
    }

    public BigDecimal getIntersetRate() {
        return intersetRate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof InterestRate)) return false;
        InterestRate that = (InterestRate) o;
        return Objects.equals(getPeriodFrom(), that.getPeriodFrom()) && Objects.equals(getPeriodEnd(), that.getPeriodEnd()) && Objects.equals(getIntersetRate(), that.getIntersetRate());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getPeriodFrom(), getPeriodEnd(), getIntersetRate());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InterestRate{" +
                "periodFrom=" + periodFrom +
                ", periodEnd=" + periodEnd +
                ", intersetRate=" + intersetRate +
                '}' +
        "\n" ;
    }

    public boolean isSelectable(InterestRate rate, LocalDate compareAgainstFrom,
                                LocalDate compareAgainstTo) {
        return (rate.getPeriodFrom().isAfter(compareAgainstFrom) ||
                rate.getPeriodFrom().isEqual(compareAgainstFrom)) &&
                (rate.getPeriodFrom().isBefore(compareAgainstTo) ||
                        rate.getPeriodFrom().isEqual(compareAgainstTo));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<InterestRate> lio = new ArrayList<>();
        LocalDate compareAgainstFrom = LocalDate.of(2018, 8, 15);
        LocalDate compareAgainstTo = LocalDate.of(2019, 11, 25);
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 1), LocalDate.of(2018, 6, 30), BigDecimal.valueOf(8.5)));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2018, 7, 1), LocalDate.of(2018, 12, 31), BigDecimal.valueOf(7.5)));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 1), LocalDate.of(2019, 6, 30), BigDecimal.valueOf(9.01)));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2019, 7, 1), LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 31), BigDecimal.valueOf(9.25)));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 1), LocalDate.of(2020, 6, 30), BigDecimal.valueOf(9.45)));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2020, 7, 1), LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 31), BigDecimal.valueOf(9.90)));


        List<InterestRate> collection = lio.stream().filter(s -> s.isSelectable(s,
                compareAgainstFrom, compareAgainstTo)).collect(Collectors.toList());


        System.out.println(collection);

    }
}
```

===============

But this returns only two , it does not return the period that contains the interest rates for 2018 august to 31st dec ..

```
    InterestRate{periodFrom=2019-01-01, periodEnd=2019-06-30, intersetRate=9.01},
    InterestRate{periodFrom=2019-07-01, periodEnd=2019-12-31, intersetRate=9.25}
```

I dont suppose this logic is correct

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a Q/A forum.

Comment: I dont have a logic for this .. the logic I tried is similar to the one in the answer but it does not give me the correct results ..I need the interest rates for the entire period

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (be aware that performance might not be the best), and this piece of code can be a good start. I guess, maybe

```
package my.project.calc;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
public class InterestRate {
    private final LocalDate periodFrom;
    private final LocalDate periodEnd;
    private final BigDecimal intersetRate;

    public InterestRate(LocalDate periodFrom, LocalDate periodEnd,
                        BigDecimal intersetRate) {
        this.periodFrom = periodFrom;
        this.periodEnd = periodEnd;
        this.intersetRate = intersetRate;
    }

    public LocalDate getPeriodFrom() {
        return periodFrom;
    }

    public LocalDate getPeriodEnd() {
        return periodEnd;
    }

    public BigDecimal getIntersetRate() {
        return intersetRate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof InterestRate)) return false;
        InterestRate that = (InterestRate) o;
        return Objects.equals(getPeriodFrom(), that.getPeriodFrom()) && Objects.equals(getPeriodEnd(), that.getPeriodEnd()) && Objects.equals(getIntersetRate(), that.getIntersetRate());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getPeriodFrom(), getPeriodEnd(), getIntersetRate());
    }

    public boolean isSelectable(InterestRate rate, LocalDate compareAgainstFrom,
                                LocalDate compareAgainstTo) {
        return (rate.getPeriodFrom().isAfter(compareAgainstFrom) ||
                rate.getPeriodFrom().isEqual(compareAgainstFrom)) &&
                (rate.getPeriodFrom().isBefore(compareAgainstTo) ||
                        rate.getPeriodFrom().isEqual(compareAgainstTo));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<InterestRate> lio = new ArrayList<>();
        LocalDate compareAgainstFrom = LocalDate.of(2006, 9, 10);
        LocalDate compareAgainstTo = LocalDate.now();
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2005, 9, 7), LocalDate.of(2015, 9, 7), BigDecimal.ONE));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2001, 9, 7), LocalDate.of(2010, 9, 7), BigDecimal.ONE));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2002, 9, 7), LocalDate.of(2020, 9, 7), BigDecimal.ONE));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2003, 9, 7), LocalDate.of(2013, 9, 7), BigDecimal.ONE));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2004, 9, 7), LocalDate.of(2016, 9, 7), BigDecimal.ONE));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2006, 9, 7), LocalDate.of(2009, 9, 7), BigDecimal.ONE));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2008, 9, 7), LocalDate.of(2017, 9, 7), BigDecimal.ONE));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2009, 9, 7), LocalDate.of(2014, 9, 7), BigDecimal.ONE));
        lio.add(new InterestRate(LocalDate.of(2000, 9, 7), LocalDate.of(2000, 9, 7), BigDecimal.ONE));

        long counto = lio.stream().filter(s -> s.isSelectable(s,
                compareAgainstFrom, compareAgainstTo)).count();

        System.out.println(counto);

    }
```

try this

```
public boolean isSelectable(InterestRate rate, LocalDate compareAgainstFrom,
                            LocalDate compareAgainstTo) {
    return ((rate.getPeriodFrom().isEqual(compareAgainstFrom) ||
                    rate.getPeriodFrom().isAfter(compareAgainstFrom)) ||
            (rate.getPeriodEnd().isEqual(compareAgainstFrom) ||
                    rate.getPeriodEnd().isAfter(compareAgainstFrom)))&&
            (rate.getPeriodFrom().isEqual(compareAgainstTo) ||
                    rate.getPeriodFrom().isBefore(compareAgainstTo)) ||
            (rate.getPeriodEnd().isEqual(compareAgainstTo) ||
                    rate.getPeriodEnd().isBefore(compareAgainstTo));
}
```

Comment: I tried this already before posting this .. but this does not return the correct result .. I have updated my question modifying the code with the values .. you can check for yourself . It should return 3 records not two .. I dont suppose we can use this logic ...

Comment: try updating isSelectable method